# Require a perl(Git) package?

Tags: git, centos6, epel

I have never received this error before when installing Git:

```
Error: Package: git-1.7.1-8.el6.x86_64 (base) Requires: perl(Git)
```

It's straightforward, required perl(Git). I would like to know why I am getting this error. I have a centos 6.8 with php 5.4. Also, can I get this from the epel_repo?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to install such an ancient version of git?

Comment: @1615903, I wasn't trying to install any particular version. I just typed yum install git.